# Powershell 2.0 Copy-Item with Exclude is not excluding the files to be excluded

Tags: powershell-2.0, copy-item

I want to copy all files and sub-folders from one folder to another using powershell script
I tried using "get-help copy-item" on powershell which says I can copy items with -Exclude to exclude the files i don't want to copy. So i am using following script

```
param($SourceDir,$OutDir)
$TempDir=$OutDir
$TestFiles = get-childitem $SourceDir -exclude *.ps1 -recurse
$TestFiles = Get-ChildItem $SourceDir -recurse -Exclude *.txt
Copy-Item $SourceDir $TempDir -recurse -Exclude *.txt
```

But when i see the folder pointed bu $OutDir, I see all files including .txt files copied over. 
Also when I am debugging using Powershell ISE, I see that $TestFiles object does not have any .txt files.

Can you tell me if there is anything wrong with the way I am using Copy-Item or suggest if there is any other way to copy both subfolders and files using powershell?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your telling it to copy one directory to another. Instead, tell powershell to copy everything inside the directory, that way it will actually go through each file, and exclude the txt files..

```
Copy-item $SourceDir\* $TempDir -exclude *.txt
```

I'm guessing the recurse parameter doesn't actually do what you might be expecting it to in this case : [Copy-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849793.aspx)

Comment: I trie the way you suggested, but all it did was not copy the $SourceDir but copied everything inside $SourceDir and again exclude did not work

Comment: @RahulLodha That is very strange man. I tested this in all versions, and it for sure works, so you must be doing something differently.